# How to have an NSSlider send a message with an argument to an object?

Tags: cocoa, selector

At runtime, I am creating a NSSlider inside an NSMenu. I would like a message to be sent to a target object, but that message also requires a float argument.

So far, I have managed to do this by keeping a pointer on the NSSlider:

```
NSSlider * widthSlider = [[NSSlider alloc] 
                           initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(16, 0, 150, 32)];
[widthSlider setMinValue:0.1];
[widthSlider setMaxValue:10];
[widthSlider setTarget:self];
 widthSliderRef=widthSlider;
[widthSlider setAction:@selector(updateLW:)];
[...]
-(void) updateLW:(id)sender {
[self setLW:[widthSliderRef doubleValue]]; }
```

Now I would like to get rid of the `widthSliderRef`.

I would like the NSSlider to send `setLW:` to `self` with its `doublevalue` as argument.

How can it be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sender` argument to `updateLW:` should be the slider -- you can just send `doubleValue` to that.